# Killing all chrome instances on Linux (debian) in python doesn't work

Tags: python, linux, server, debian

On a debian Linux server I tried to run a python script with in the python script the following line of code:

```
subprocess.call('pkill Chrome')
```

but this caused the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pkill Chrome'
```

Expecting that it was the command that failed I tried a few different things like writing `sudo` before the pkill and writing `chrome` in stead of `Chrome` but nothing worked. Any ideas how I can kill all chrome instances? Thanks in advance!

Btw, I also tried the same line but with the `killall chrome` command resulting in a similar error.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. The thing that solved it for me was to set the variable ```shell=True```.  Using ```shell=True``` it worked with both a list of args and a single string, that did not seem to make a difference in the result.

Comment: Please post the preceding comment as an answer to your own question.